# Dense sets and measurability

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, measure-theory

This is a problem from my Real Analysis course. I would only like a hint in the right direction.

Let S be any dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Let $f:E\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Prove $f$ is measurable $\iff$ $\{f>\alpha\}$ is measurable for each $\alpha \in S$.

I was given as a hint that I could make a sequence $S_n\in S$ which converges to $-\infty$. So this is what I thought:

$\Rightarrow$ Assume $f$ is measurable. Let $\{S_n\}$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$ be a sequence in $S$ converging to $-\infty$. For each $\alpha_n \in \{S_n\}$, there exists a corresponding set $\{f>\alpha_n\}$. Take $\mathcal{O}_n=\bigcup\limits_{i\in \mathbb{N}}{\mathcal{O}_n}_i$ to be the open set which covers a particular $\{f>\alpha_n\}$. Since $f$ is measurable, each open set $\mathcal{O}_n\in f(E)$ has an inverse image $f^{-1}(\mathcal{O}_n)\in E$ by proposition 2 p. 55 $\textit{Royden, Fitzpatrick}$. Define $E_n=f^{-1}(\mathcal{O}_n)$. Since each $O_n$ is measurable, $E_n$ is also measurable. Thus $E=\bigcup\limits_{n\in \mathbb{N}}E_n$ is a countable set, which is also measurable. Hence, by proposition 1  p. 54 $\textit{Royden, Fitzpatrick}$, the set $\{f>\alpha\}$ for all $\alpha\in S$ is measurable.

Could anyone provide why we're able to choose such a sequence? (I think that S being dense is why, but I'm not sure.)

Also, is my proof going one way even close to being right?

Comment: What is your definition of measurable? I think $f$ is measurable if and only if $\{ f > \alpha\}$ is measurable for $\alpha \in \mathbb R$. Then one direction should be trivial. For the other, use the sigma algebra structure of measurable sets.

Comment: A function $f$ is measurable if it is has a measurable domain E and $\{f>\alpha\}$ (or another inequality) is measurable.

Comment: so one way is obvious, right?

Comment: The other way seems more intuitive, but overall no. Are you trying to tell me I'm doing too much work?

Comment: No, you are correct. May be we can reduce the size of your answer, though.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a Theorem in Wheeden's book, for $E$ dense in $\mathbb{R}$, $\forall a \in \mathbb{R}$, you can find a sequence $\{a_k\}\subset E,\; a_k \rightarrow a$ and $a_k\ge a$. Then $\{x:f>a\}=\bigcup_k\{x:f>a_k\}$, this follows the measurability.